# How to select a profile image form OS's file systems

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Can I create a game with cocos2d-x which allows to browse system files and select profile picture for a player? Or in general is there a file select feature?

Comment: Yes, you can. No, there isn't. You should make your own dialog in cocos2d-x, that under the hood uses either `std::fstream`, `std::filesystem` or whatever.

Comment: @Drop it is not a small deal. Is there any 3rd party solution available? which can be wrapped with GUI?